# Making a Limit X,Y MySQL Query with Joins Run Faster

Tags: mysql, database, join, query-optimization

I have a MySQL query with a particular structure that I want to rewrite so that it runs faster.   It currently runs very slow taking about 255 seconds to execute.  If I remove the join it runs in < 10 seconds.  Its purpose is to get records from table A, 100 rows at a time, for as long as a user wants to see more rows.

I suspect that the query is taking a long time because it's doing the join on more than just the first 100 rows it finds.  Is this true, and if so, is there a way to rewrite the query to do the joining after it gets the rows from the main table?

The data comes from a 'main' table A which has a datetime field (START_TIME) and several foreign keys to tables with string values (tables, B,C,D).

Table A has 2.5 million rows.  Table B has 600K rows.
Table A has an index on START_TIME.  Table B has an index on its ID value.

Here's a basic form of the query.  I do not want to put an upper limit on START_TIME because I ALWAYS want to get 100 records back from the query. I use a response which has less than 100 records to indicate that there`s no more records in the database.

```
SELECT 
    A.START_TIME, A.F1, A.F2, B.STRING
FROM 
    A
     INNER JOIN B ON A.B_ID = B.ID
WHERE
    A.START_TIME >= '2015-03-22 05:23:44'
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Here`s the EXPLAIN. Sorry for the format:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, SIMPLE, B, index, PRIMARY, FSN, 95, , 1, Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1, SIMPLE, A, ref, A_ix_B_ID,A_ix_C, A_ix_B_ID, 4, ag100_a$$burnaby.B.ID, 2, Using where
```

Comment: You can use `ctrl-k` to format text as code.

Comment: Now you have to try adding one table at each time http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/ You should try every select be type `index`

Comment: Here`s the results of adding one table at a time:  Just table A: 8.7 seconds, tables A and B: 255 seconds.  The problem still remains, and my original question remains: is there a way of restructuring this query so the joins are done after the records are retrieved from table A.  This is very important to know as this is a very common query.

Comment: So you say the time in second and expect we give you a solution?  without a plan? Give us details. How many rows are in A, how many are in B. How many A match `A.START_TIME >= '2015-03-22 05:23:44' How many `A.ID` match `B.ID`

Comment: As per your question for the number of rows in A and B, that information appears in my post and has always been in my post.

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052561/does-a-mysql-query-with-from-a-inner-join-b-limit-x-y-do-the-join-before-or

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY`, which 100 rows are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide explain plan so we can help you better.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html

But for your description you still need index.

TableA beside `START_TIME` need index for each join field `B_id, C_id and D_id` and maybe using a composite index for all 4 variable would be better

```
 CREATE INDEX A_Bid_idx ON A (B_id);
 CREATE INDEX A_Cid_idx ON A (C_id);
 CREATE INDEX A_Did_idx ON A (D_id);

 OR

 CREATE INDEX A_Full_idx ON A (B_id,C_id, D_id, START_TIME);
```

Table C and D also need index for `C.ID and D.ID`. And would be even better if they use a composite index

```
  (C.ID, C.STRING)  and
  (D.ID, D.STRING)

  CREATE INDEX C_id_idx ON C (ID);
  CREATE INDEX D_id_idx ON D (ID);

  OR

  CREATE INDEX C_id_string_idx ON C (ID, STRING);
  CREATE INDEX D_id_string_idx ON C (ID, STRING);
```

That way db doesnt have to make a lookup to find the string value asociated to the ID

Comment: Regarding a better explanation, what else would you like to know?  But isn`t the biggest time savings found by doing to the joins AFTER the 100 records are found?  I`ll add the index`s you suggest above and retry.

Comment: As I say you still need some index. You have to show us the explain plan to see where is the problem http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/mysql/getting-an-execution-plan

Comment: Please help me out.  I don`t know what other information to give to you.

Comment: On average, any B_ID value appears only 4 times in Table A.  I don`t think putting that in a composite index would help.  Remember table B has 600K rows.

Comment: Read the link i give you. that will show you how `EXPLAIN <query>`  works

Comment: I disagree, specially because the number is low the index will be more relevant, but you will have to test it and check what option add more improvement. I can only give you the tips. You have to do the testing.

Comment: Added the indexes on C and D.  Execution time is 257 seconds, still way to long.   I`m very sure this query is doing joins on more than 100 records of the response.  I don`t need it to do that.  How do I stop it from doing that?

Comment: I told you show us the explain plan. Otherwise we dont know what is doing your query

Comment: Sorry, I didn`t recognize the `explain plan` term although I am familiar with the EXPLAIN command.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  A.START_TIME, A.F1, A.F2, 
      ( SELECT  STRING
            FROM  B
            WHERE  A.B_ID = B.ID 
      ) AS String
    FROM  A
    WHERE  A.START_TIME >= '2015-03-22 05:23:44'
    ORDER BY START_TIME
    LIMIT  0, 100;
```

will probably run faster.  It is 'forced' to use `INDEX(START_TIME)` from `A`.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables; I want to check the datatypes, etc.