# Does a MySQL query with `from A inner join B ...LIMIT x,y` do the join before or after getting the y rows out of table A?

Tags: mysql, join

For the following command below

1. Does MySQL do the joins before or after getting the 100 rows from
   the table A?
2. Is there a way to rewrite the query to get the rows
   from table A before the joins are made?

   ```
   SELECT
      A.START_TIME, A.F1, A.F2, B.STRING
   FROM    
      A INNER JOIN B ON A.B_ID=B.ID
   WHERE
      A.START_TIME>= '2015-03-22 05:23:44'
   LIMIT 0, 100;
   ```

Comment: use the Explain command to get the execution plan for a query http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, the limit is applied **after** the join on the combined dataset.
2. If you want to apply the limit on table A only before the join, then you need to use a subquery:

`SELECT
   T.START_TIME, T.F1, T.F2, B.STRING
FROM

   (select A.START_TIME, A.F1, A.F2 from A WHERE A.START_TIME>= '2015-03-22 05:23:44' limit 0, 100) T INNER JOIN B ON T.B_ID=B.ID;`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL query execution engine applies `LIMIT` by counting the result set rows and stopping once the target count has been reached. Generally if you have a key on `START_TIME` in `A` and on `ID` in `B`, and the records found in `A` usually have a match in `B`, this query should be very fast. If the join order is `A,B` (which should happen with the above keys), then the result rows are produced as the execution works its way through A going through the index, then if a match is found in `B`, the row is output and immediately becomes available to check against the counter from `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

1-It gets all of rows then makes JOIN

```
2- SELECT
   A.START_TIME, A.F1, A.F2, B.STRING
FROM    
   A **!LEFT!** JOIN B ON A.B_ID=B.ID
WHERE
   A.START_TIME>= '2015-03-22 05:23:44'
LIMIT 0, 100;
```